# Unity Android receiving signal crashes

Tags: unity-game-engine, unity-player-android

**Backstory**

I built my unity app to android x64 using IL2CPP which has worked fine in the past but after a lot of changes I'm now getting crashes somewhat spontaneously.

Signals received:

- signal 6 (SIGABRT), code -1 (SI_QUEUE)
- signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 2 (SEGV_ACCERR)
- signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1 (SEGV_MAPERR)
- signal 7 (SIGBUS), code 1 (BUS_ADRALN)

I don't have much to go on other than I only get see this crash on android, not my 64bit win11 unity editor nor 32bit Android (still built with il2cpp).

**Question**

Where do I even start to troubleshoot this ?

**Potential Solution**

While gathering information to post this question I stumbled across a solution although I'm still 100% sure of the underlying issue.

- Knowing that builds store some IL2CPP cache for subsequent builds I decided to switch build types
- I set Build Settings > Player Settings > Android Settings > Scripting Backend to "Mono"
- No signal crashes
- I set the Scripting Backend back to IL2CPP and still not signal crashes

My best guess is bad cache from a previous build.

Comment: If you're worries about cache you should be able to initialise a clean build with the dropdown on the build button?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone else who runs into this issue: it seems il2cpp related. The easiest fix seems to be switching build type (il2ccp <> mono) and back. Sometimes I've had to go as far as a mixture of cleaning the build from within android studio and/or cleaning the build from unity, followed by resetting my .git project with `$ git checkout .`.